# Stream thread Null pointer error

Tags: java, android

I am currently having a problem with retrieving an object from a stream in a thread. I am currently getting a null pointer error where it is trying to read from a stream. The input stream is instantiated in a service class so that only one connection for the app is needed. Can anyone see if there is any obvious reason as to why i am getting a null pointer error.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true){
            while ((mess = (com.DrawTastic.Message) messRec.readObject()) != null) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        mAdapter.add(mess);

                    }
                });
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

error trace:

```
03-27 23:08:10.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2218): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
03-27 23:08:10.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2218): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 23:08:10.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at com.DrawTastic.ChatActivity.run(ChatActivity.java:149)
03-27 23:08:10.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Slightly OT but why is the loop testing for null? Are you sending null? or are you under the misapprehension that `readObject()` returns null at end of stream? It doesn't, it throws `EOFException`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume mess must be a class-level field, or else this would fail to compile.  But basically, all the `Runnable`s you construct share the *same* reference to mess, which...is null by the time the loop ends.

Instead, it's probably preferable to copy `mess` to a local final variable:

```
final Message thisMess = mess;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    mAdapter.add(thisMess);
  }
});
```

...Assuming that it's running asynchronously, I don't know Android well enough to know.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe  `mAdapter` is `null`.